# Git add does not add the folder and files that are copied in Windows

Tags: git, github

I unzipped and copied a folder (with files in them) to the directory project directory with Git then I did:

```
git add .
```

But this does not seem to add this folder at all.

I also tried `git status` but nothing seems to be showing up there either.

Is there something that I need to do to fix this?

Comment: What about git add *?

Comment: I tried that one but no luck...

Comment: What is the git status output?  Is it something like: # On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: That's right. Nothing to commit

Comment: Possibly there is something in your .gitignore which is causing the new folder to be ignored?  Also, are you trying to do the git add . command from the root directory of the project?

Comment: Yes I am and there's not gitignore file in that directory also in the root one there's no line blocking it

Comment: Not looking likely but worth checking: there are [other sources for ignore patterns](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html). `cd that/dir; git ls-files --exclude-standard --oi`, see what comes up.

Comment: Are you sure you are in a Git tracked directory? What does `git rev-parse --git-dir` show? How about `git config --list`. If you are, `git status` should show those files as untracked, and `git add .` should work, but you might want to try `git add --all .`.